# Combine lvs without direct sum or tensor product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For a finite number of finite dimension linear vector spaces we have two common, well defined means of combining them to make a new vector space:  Direct sum/direct product and tensor product.  What other well-defined methods exist, if any?

Answer (score 2):

Another important basic one is that given two vector spaces $V, W$ we can produce the vector space $[V, W]$ (also notated $\text{Hom}(V, W)$) of linear maps $V \to W$. More complicated examples can be built by iterating these constructions to form "polynomials" such as $(V \otimes W) \oplus (V^{\otimes 2} \otimes W^{\otimes 2})$.

Conversely one might ask for a classification of all such things. (This part of the answer will require much more background to understand.) This requires a way to make more precise what we really mean by a way of combining vector spaces to form a new vector space. One possible formalization is that we want [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor): all of the examples discussed so far are functors, although $[V, W]$ is [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance) in $V$. So one might ask for a classification of functors

$$\text{Vect} \times \text{Vect} \to \text{Vect}$$

or something like that, maybe finite-dimensional vector spaces specifically. A very large class of examples, which I think exhausts all "reasonable" examples, is given by the following class of "multivariate power series": let $C_{n, m}$ be any family of [representations of the product of [symmetric groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $S_n \times S_m$, and take the functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory)

$$(V, W) \mapsto \sum_{n, m \ge 0} C_{n, m} \otimes_{S_n \times S_m} V^{\otimes n} \otimes W^{\otimes m}$$

where, if $V, W$ are two representations of a group $G$, $V \otimes_G W$ is the quotient of $V \otimes W$ by the relation $gv \otimes w \sim v \otimes gw$ for all $g \in G$. The single-variable version of this construction is called taking Schur functors, so one might call these multivariate Schur functors. A similar construction works for more than two inputs.

This describes constructions taking in vector spaces and producing vector spaces; I actually don't know the answer to the corresponding question for finite-dimensional vector spaces. We can restrict our attention to "polynomials" with f.d. coefficients, but this doesn't exhaust all examples; for example, in one variable the "power series"

$$V \mapsto \sum_{n \ge 0} \Lambda^n(V)$$

where $\Lambda^n(V)$ is the $\text{sign} \otimes_{S_n} V^{\otimes n}$ (so this whole construction is the exterior algebra) sends f.d. vector spaces to f.d. vector spaces despite not being a "polynomial." I actually don't know a complete classification here.

Comment: Thanks.  Regarding the space of linear maps between the two spaces it's not immediately obvious to me that it is a vector space.  Is there a good reference that proves that?  Any special conditions?   Also I should have stated that I'm most interested in the case that these are inner product spaces, and the most interesting case is that the resultant space is one also.  Is that true in general in the linear maps case?

Comment: @Jim: it's a good exercise; the vector space operations are all given pointwise, and there are no conditions. The inner product space case is somewhat different and I haven't thought much about it; it's a little tricky to get the result to also be an inner product space.